# Knockout: click binding to add/remove item in hierarchy

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I would like to understand how to call add/delete functions from within a knockout hierarchy.  For example, if I am inside nested foreach, and I click on a delete button, how can I call a function that will let me delete the item (and do some other things too)?

Here's a Fiddle of the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/4a3z4urc/

In the html, the commented-out button works, but I need the function to be inside my script tags (which isn't working).

```
function ViewModel(data){
    var self = this;
    self.pages = ko.mapping.fromJS( data );
    self.OutputJson = function(){
        console.log(ko.toJSON(self));
    }

    self.removePage = function(pageName) { self.pages.remove(pageName) };
    self.removeRow = function(rowType) { self.pages.pageRows.remove(rowType) };
    self.removeSlide = function(slide) { self.slides.remove(slide)  };
    self.addSlide = function(slide) {}
}
```

How can I make the RemoveRow and RemoveSlide functions delete the correct item?  (Json is shown below the demo).  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that in your "inner" `remove` method you don't have the information of the "currently selected" page, pageRow, slide, etc.

One solution would be to pass in the current `$parent` into your click handlers:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: pageRows">
    <section style="border:1px solid pink; padding:5px;">

      <button type="submit" data-bind="click: $root.removeRow.bind($parent, $data)" 
          class="btn-delete"><i>&times;</i></button>

     ...
   </section>
</div>
```

And now you can access the "currently selected" page with `this` in your handler:

```
self.removeRow = function(rowType) { this.pageRows.remove(rowType) };
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/).

Note that you also need to use `$root` to access the "top level" if you inside are multiple `foreach` bindings.

You can also pass in the `$parent` as a paramter: `root.removeRow.bind(null, $parent, $data)`, and in this case your handle would look like this:

```
self.removeRow = function(page, rowType) { page.pageRows.remove(rowType) };
```

You can read more about the different [additional paramter passing options in the documentation.](http://note-2-accessing-the-event-object-or-passing-more-parameters)

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!  Tell me, will it be possible to add a slide when using knockout mapping plugin?  I am able to do it myself on top level only.

Comment: You can just add new items to observablearray fine even when using the mapping plugin. You just have to identify the current page, pageRow etc. to do so, however it would be esier to explain this if you would add the necessery details of how you plan to do this, in a seprate question.

Comment: Additional question added here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994245/knockout-add-items-into-nested-json-hierarchy